# Why the start command behaves one way in win7 and another in win10?

Tags: cmd, windows-7, windows-10

In windows 7 if I execute

```
for /l %i in (1,1,10) do @start calc
```

it will open 10 different calc applications. If I do the same in windows 10 it'll open just one application. But, if I execute

```
for /l %i in (1,1,10) do @start calc & pause
```

after every `pause` a new calc application will be opened. So, what I'd like to know is why the `start` command behaves differently in win7 and win10? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe this is because of the renewed `calc` application in Windows 10; in Windows 7 there is just `calc.exe` running; but in Windows 10, `calc.exe` seems to run another executable which actually constitutes the Calculator...

Comment: The actual calculator.exe app is in a subdirectory of the hidden "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps" directory. A single process hosts all calculator windows. Try waiting for the initial window to be created and then create 9 more in succession without `pause`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on Windows 10.  I know it looks like it shouldn't because of the `/wait` option but it does work.

```
for /l %i in (1,1,10) do cmd /c start /wait calc
```

Actually do not need `cmd /c`.

```
for /l %i in (1,1,10) do start /wait calc
```

Comment: It works! Exactly looks like it won't work but it does. Why the `/wait` doesn't wait for `calc` and does wait, let's say, for `notepad`?